# XML Syntax attributes PHP - issue with key

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

i create a XML file using PHP

```
$xml=new SimpleXMLElement('<config/>');
$xml->addAttribute("xmlns","http://www.toto.com/tot_config_20110606");
$xml->addAttribute("xmlns:xsi","http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
$xml->addAttribute("xsi:schemaLocation","http://www.toto.com/tot_config_20110606 config.xsd"); 

   //some childrens...

file_put_contents($filename, $xml->asXML() , LOCK_EX);
```

the result is a correct XML file but i have a problem with the attributes

the result is:

```
<config xmlns="http://www.toto.com/tot_config_20110606" xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" schemaLocation="http://www.toto.com/tot_config_20110606 config.xsd">
   //...
</config>
```

Does someone can explain me how to keep the entire key ?

but i need this result with the first part of the attributes:

```
<config  xmlns="http://www.toto.com/tot_config_20110606" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.toto.com/tot_config_20110606 config.xsd">
   //...
</config>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the suggestion by one *p.servus* made [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.addattribute.php) and add the parent schema's URL as a third parameter for `addAttribute()`:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement("<config></config>");
$xml->addAttribute("xmlns","http://www.toto.com/tot_config_20110606");
/***** Update: the following line must be deleted****/
// $xml->addAttribute("xmlns:xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance", "http://www.toto.com/tot_config_20110606"); 
$xml->addAttribute("xsi:schemaLocation", "http://www.toto.com/tot_config_20110606 config.xsd", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"); 
echo $xml->asXml();
```

Comment: Thanks  that's work without the 3rd line @SergeyVidusov  but that help me a lot  Good job guy